# How Can I Understand this Vendor-Specific SMART Attribute?

Tags: hard-drive, smart, drive-failure

There are two contexts for this question, a general and a specific.

**Generally,** how does one find the meaning for vendor-specific S.M.A.R.T. attributes? I have searched the web high and low but found only partial information. Are there hard-to-find repositories that document this information?

**Specifically,** for the Western Digital drive pictured below (`WDC WD4003FZEX-00Z4SA0`), how should I interpret the vendor-specific SMART attribute ID `10` (10 Hex, 16 Decimal)?

From my understanding, a lower value indicates a more serious problem, but I can find no information on this particular ID.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I can't phrase it better than [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.):

> *The term `"S.M.A.R.T."` refers only to a signaling method between internal disk drive electromechanical sensors and the host computer. Because of this the specifications of S.M.A.R.T. are entirely vendor specific and, while many of these attributes have been standardized between drive vendors, others remain vendor-specific.
>
> ...
>
> issues remain due to **attributes intentionally left undocumented** to the public in order to differentiate models between manufacturers
>
> ...
>
> manufacturers do not necessarily agree on precise attribute definitions and measurement units
>
> ...*

So your best bet to understand all attributes of a specific disk and their implication is to use the vendor supplied tool, such as for instance the [Western Digital Dashboard](https://support.wdc.com/downloads.aspx?p=279&lang=en)

Generic tools, although they can read all the supplied S.M.A.R.T. attributes, may not have the complete picture to interpret non-standard attributes in a meaningful way; displaying those as `Vendor Specific` is technically correct.

https://kb.acronis.com/content/9110 ;

> **Attribute ID**: `10 (0x0A)`
> **Hard drives, supporting this attribute**: Samsung, Seagate, IBM (Hitachi), Fujitsu, Maxtor, Western Digital
> **Description**:  Spin Retry Count S.M.A.R.T. parameter indicates the count of retry of spin start attempts. This attribute stores a total count of the spin start attempts to reach the fully operational speed (under the condition that the first attempt was unsuccessful). Spin attempts are counted for the entire hard drive's lifetime so far.